# How to classify strings in a list given it contains determined characters, python

Tags: python, list

in the following list:

```
es_texts = ['dando lo mejor de mi!!', 'dando lo mejor de mi', 'La felicidad es irremplazable', 'Nos vamos de paseo', '¿Nos vamos de paseo?', 'Nos vamos de paseo?']
```

I would like to separate the strings into 2 lists, one that contains determined characters like "?", "!", etc.., As long as it contains one of the given characters it should go `list_include`, if not, should be appended to `list_exclude`, for example:

```
list_include = ['dando lo mejor de mi!!', '¿Nos vamos de paseo?', 'Nos vamos de paseo?']

list_exclude = ['dando lo mejor de mi', 'La felicidad es irremplazable', 'Nos vamos de paseo']
```

I tried:

```
list_include = []
list_exclude = []

for item in es_texts:
  if "?","!" in item:
    list_include.append(item)
  else:
    list_exclude.append(item)

print('list_include = ', list_include)
print('list_exclude = ', list_exclude)
```

But I get a invalid syntax, how do I manage to have an "OR" argument between "?","!" ?

Comment: What is `items`? Should be `if "?" in item`

Comment: `if "?" in item or "!" in item:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
list_include = [s for s in es_texts if any([x in s for x in '?!'])]
list_exclude = [s for s in es_texts if s not in list_include]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need `str.endswith`

**Ex:**

```
es_texts = ['dando lo mejor de mi!!', 'dando lo mejor de mi', 'La felicidad es irremplazable', 'Nos vamos de paseo', '¿Nos vamos de paseo?', 'Nos vamos de paseo?']

list_include = []
list_exclude = []
for item in es_texts:
    if item.endswith(("?", "!")):   # OR if any(i in item for i in ("?", "!")):
        list_include.append(item)
    else:
        list_exclude.append(item)

print(list_include)
print(list_exclude)
```

**Output:**

```
['dando lo mejor de mi!!', '¿Nos vamos de paseo?', 'Nos vamos de paseo?']
['dando lo mejor de mi', 'La felicidad es irremplazable', 'Nos vamos de paseo']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
es_texts = ['dando lo mejor de mi!!', 'dando lo mejor de mi', 'La felicidad es irremplazable', 'Nos vamos de paseo', '¿Nos vamos de paseo?', 'Nos vamos de paseo?']
list_include = [x for x in es_texts if "?" in x or "!" in x]
list_exclude = [x for x in es_texts if x not in list_include]
print(list_include)
print(list_exclude)
```